# MongoEngine: query objects filtered from multiple fields

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

How to use MongoEngine to query and filter for objects from the relationship of values between fields of the same object?

I'm trying to use MongoEngine (0.15.0) for objects having the following criteria:

```
max(field_a, field_b, field_c) <= constant_value
```

Where `field_a`, `field_b` and `field_c` is a property of the same MongoDB document.

I’ve looked at the [MongoEngine documentation](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#filtering-queries) and it looks like filters are limited to single fields. But I could be missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

As provided in the documentation link you shared, the Q class can be used in MongoEngine to combine a number of constraints using *and* and *or*.
Following piece of code may help satisfy your criteria:

```
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q

# Get published posts
Document.objects(Q(field_a__lte=constant_value) & Q(field_b__lte=constant_value) & Q(field_c__lte=constant_value))
```